# Is there such a thing as a partial $0$-ary function?

Tags: partial-functions

I know that there are partial binary operations and partial unary operations, but is there such a thing as a partial $0$-ary function (which is not total, of course)?

Comment: To me, "a 0-ary function" sounds like a pretentious way to say "a constant".

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'd say not just any constant, but a constant that has for domain $X^\emptyset$, i.e. a constant that has for domain $\{\emptyset\}$. ;)

Comment: I think a partial 0-ary function makes sense. I don't think anything stops the $n$-ary definition from working when $n = 0$. If you use $0$-ary functions to implement constants, then it's pretty much required to allow them to be partial if you want to define compositions for arbitrary partial functions! A $0$-ary function which is not total then basically represents an "undefined value". See also eg the `Maybe` monad from functional programming.

Comment: @peterwhy Why? Isn't the empty function a partial function on any domain (in particular, the domain with a single element)?

Comment: @AlexKruckman It seems that I misunderstood when I commented; I might have read the "partial" with "not total" conditions, and disregarded partial functions that are undefined for every argument.